# A problem with a proof about formal series in Lang's Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, power-series, local-rings

Theorem in question is:

> Let $\mathfrak o$ be a complete local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$. Let $$ f(X) = \sum_{i = 0} a_iX^i $$be a power series in $\mathfrak o
> [[X]]$ such that not all $a_i$ lie in $\mathfrak m$.
>   Let $a_0, \ldots, a_{n-1} \in \mathfrak m$ and $a_n \in \mathfrak o^\times$ is a unit.
>   Given $g \in \mathfrak o
> [[X]]$ we can solve the equation
>   $$g = qf + r$$
>   uniquely with $q \in \mathfrak o [[X]], r \in \mathfrak o [X], \deg r < n$.

For those who have access to book, this is chapter IV (Polynomials), subchapter 9 (Power series). For those without a book, I'll transcribe Lang's proof:

Let $\alpha$ and $\tau$ be projections on the beginning and tail end of the series, given by:
$$ \alpha : \sum b_i X^i \to b_0 + b_1 X + \ldots b_{n-1}X^{n-1},$$
$$ \tau : \sum b_i X^i \to b_n + b_{n+1} X + b_{n+2}X^2 + \ldots .$$

Notice:

1. $\tau(X^n h) = h$ for all $h \in \mathfrak o[[X]]$.
2. $h$ is a polynomial of $< n$ if and only if $\tau(h) = 0$.

The existence of $q, r$ is equivalent with a condition that there exists
$q$ such that
$$ \tau(g) = \tau(qf).$$

We can write $f = \alpha(f) + X^n \tau(f)$, hence our problem is 
equivalent with solving
$$ \tau(g) = \tau(qf) = \tau(q\alpha(f)) + \tau(q X^n \tau(f)) 
= \tau(q \alpha(f)) + q\tau(f),$$
by using (1) in the last equality.

Notice that $\tau(f)$ is invertible. Writing $Z = q\tau(f)$, the equation above is equivalent with:

$$ \tau(g) = \tau \left(Z \frac{\alpha(f)}{\tau(f)}\right) + Z = \left(I + \tau \circ
\frac{\alpha(f)}{\tau(f)}\right)Z$$

**Here comes my issue with this proof.**

Note that $\alpha(f) \in \mathfrak m[[X]]$, so that image of $\tau \circ
\frac{\alpha(f)}{\tau(f)}$ is in $\mathfrak m[[X]]$.

**We can therefore invert to find $Z$, namely**
$$ Z = \left(I + \tau \circ
\frac{\alpha(f)}{\tau(f)}\right)^{-1}\tau(g).$$

---

It is not at all clear to me why this remark about image of $\tau \circ
\frac{\alpha(f)}{\tau(f)}$ implies invertibility of the function
$\bigl(I + \tau \circ
\frac{\alpha(f)}{\tau(f)}\bigr)$.
Could we write the inverse in a more concrete way?

Comment: Does anyone know why the OP's $\backslash\mathrm{bigl}($ and $\backslash\mathrm{bigr})$ are failing to embiggen the parentheses?

Comment: @CalumGilhooley I have changed \bigl( to \left( and etc. I believe that is usually the correct way to make large parentheses.

Comment: This is a version of the Weierstrass Preparation Theorem for series over a complete local ring, and I believe that there are as many proofs as there are provers.

Comment: The reason, @CalumGilhooley, is that \bigl(, etc., makes the parentheses only slightly larger. There are also \biggl(, \Bigl(, and \Biggl(, giving various degrees of embiggenedness.

Comment: @Lubin D'oh! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can write it concretely: if $T$ is a linear transformation, we should have $$(I+T)^{-1} = I - T + T^2 - T^3 + ...$$ where the right side makes sense, i.e. where given $Z$ the series $$Z - TZ + T^2Z - T^3Z + ...$$ converges. In this context, the observation about $T = \frac{\alpha(f)}{\tau(f)} \tau $ is that $T^n Z \in \mathfrak{m}^n[[X]]$, so that the series $Z - TZ + T^2Z - ...$ converges $\mathfrak{m}$-adically in the complete ring $\mathfrak{o}$.

Comment: Presumably in your expansion of $(I+T)^{-1}$, you want alternating signs in the series.