# Clarification of Lang Theorem 9.1

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Theorem 9.1. of Serge Lang's algebra proves that if $A$ is a complete local ring with maximal ideal $I$, if

$$ f = a_0 + a_1X + \dots $$

is an element of $A[[X]]$, if $a_0,\dots,a_{n-1} \in I$ but $a_n \not \in I$, then for any $g \in A[[X]]$, there exists a unique $q \in A[[X]]$ and $r \in A[X]$ with $\deg(r) \leq n-1$ such that $f = qg + r$.

To prove this statement, Lang introduces two maps

$$ \alpha(b_0 + b_1X + \dots) = b_0 + \dots + b_{n-1} X^{n-1} $$

and

$$ \tau(b_0 + b_1X + \dots) = b_n + b_{n+1}X + \dots $$

Clearly the assumptions on $f$ imply that $\tau(f)$ is invertible since the leading coefficient of $\tau(f)$ is a unit in $A$. A key claim in the argument is that the map

$$ h \mapsto h + \tau \left( [\alpha(f)/\tau(f)] h \right) $$

is invertible, but I am unable to see how Lang is able to justify this. I am able to prove this map is injective but I have no idea how to prove the map is surjective.

Comment: I initially answered a little too hastily and made a silly error, but I believe this should answer your question: [A problem with a proof about formal series in Lang's Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901205/a-problem-with-a-proof-about-formal-series-in-langs-algebra)

Comment: Ah I see - thanks :)